# Inverse Function Theorem when determinant is undefined

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inverse

> For $f(x,y) = (x^3 - y^2, \sin{x} - \ln{y})$ f-inverse exists and is differentiable in a non-empty set around $(-1,0)$. Find $D(f^{-1})$ at $(-1,0)$.

Seemingly this is an Inverse Function Theorem problem. So I have my J matrix ($a_{ij} = \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}$):

$$\begin{vmatrix}{3x^2}&{-2y}\\{\cos{x}}&{\frac{-1}{y}}\\ \end{vmatrix}$$
and its determinant is $2y\cos{x} - \frac{3x^2}{y}$.

However, evaluating at $(-1,0)$ yields $\frac{-3}{0}$.

Can I use the IFT here where the determinant is undefined? Is it sufficient that it's not zero in the area *around* $(-1,0)$? Or did I make a mistake in calculation? How else could I answer this question?

Comment: The function is not even defined at $y=0$. How can you invert it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want **the inverse** to exist around $(-1,0)$, not $f$ to be invertible around $(-1,0)$ (as $f$ isn't defined at $(-1,0)$ this does not really make sense, as you observe). So we start to find $(x,y)$ such that $f(x,y) = (-1,0)$. We have 
$$ x^3 - y^2 = -1, \quad \sin x = \log y$$
as solution is $(0, 1)$. Now use the IFT to prove that $f$ is invertible around $(0,1)$. We have 
$$ \det Df(0,1) = 0 \cdot (-1) - (-2) \cdot 1 = 2 \ne 0. $$
For computing $D(f^{-1})(0,1)$ recall that 
$$ Df^{-1}(-1,0) = Df\bigl(f^{-1}(-1,0)\bigr)^{-1} = Df(0,1)^{-1} $$